# How to get files, changed between two changesets in GIT?

Tags: git

Sorry for the poor quality of the question itself, but I'm running into a case where the only language I know collides with the existing jargon.  Please feel free to point me in the direction of the correct jargon, since I suspect that I could have searched for this answer if I knew it.

I want to create a 'patch' using git that contains the files necessary to change from one version of a project, to another.  I don't want an actual GIT patch that updates a master based on the output of a branch, but rather something similar to a zip containing all files changed since a given update.

The situation is that I don't want to simply push the entire contents of the updated version to the server (there's lots of files that haven't been changed), but at the same time I don't want to have to go through and hand-pick around 300 files.

I know that GIT does have an FTP deployment option of some kind, but the service we're using doesn't provide that, so as far as I can tell what I need is something similar to a commercial delta patch that gets distributed whenever a company updates a product.  I find it highly unlikely that GIT doesn't provide SOMETHING similar to this functionality, but I don't know where/how to find it.

Edit:  Since it looks from one answer like it might be relevant, this if for a web application, so I'm talking about tracking css, php, html, and js files, probably with some art wound up being thrown in even though source control systems don't work well with art.

Comment: Why can't your server just track the main repository, and automatically execute `git pull` every so often?  This way, Git will figure out how best to send the changes over the wire, and the server will be up-to-date every time that it pulls from the central repo.

Comment: Because I'm doing work for a small company that rents a commercial webserver that doesn't have that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if we say about GUI-centric windows solution around GIT, I'll be able to see additional exotic perversion (Git-fanboys, sit down!!!):

**TortoiseHG (1- Windows 2 - GUI 3 - for Mercurial SCM) with hg-git extension**

Add git-repository into THG, use context-menu in changesets-pane, Export - Archive -  "Only files..."

[image: Git Repo]

[image: Archive only changes]

Both screenshots are from my git-repo, fully handled by TortoiseHG

Answer (score 4):

If piping diff to xargs is *too hard* for you, you can try

- [git-deploy](https://github.com/aizatto/git-deploy)
- [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp)
- combine `git archive` and `git diff` in form `git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)`

Comment: While I don't appreciate the condescension (not everyone uses linux, or command line tools!), you did come up with a solution that solves my current issues.

Comment: Correction, it looks like both git-deploy and git-ftp are linux tools.  I guess I'll just have to setup and learn a linux environment.

Comment: @RonLugge - both tools are based on cross-platforms environment: you can install Ruby and Python on Windows

Comment: I tried the last command and it worked perfectly! I am now trying to understand HOW it works. -o update.zip saves the output to update.zip. HEAD means we are getting the files from the current branch. git diff --name-only HEAD^ lists the files that have changed since the previous version. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ron, I hope this helps:

```
    git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD^
    CCodeClasses.cpp
    CCodeClasses.h
    CTypeClasses.cpp
    CTypeClasses.h
    CTypeResolver.cpp
    CTypeResolver.h
    DFSearch.cpp
    DFSearch.h
    Util.cpp
    Util.h
    x32wrapper.cpp
    x32wrapper.h
    mfcreplacements.h
```

where you can replace HEAD with the commit ID's you want to get the list of changed files and then pipe that to a tar command or something.  I'd love to know if there's a better way to do this, because I need to do the same thing from time to time.

Comment: Thanks, it's not a great answer but it's a lot better than the 'nothing' I had.

Comment: @RonLugge - not a great?! You have **only pipe output** of diff to xargs to deploy files!!!

Comment: Because some of the people I'm working with like nice UI-based solutions, and piping is going to be difficult enough for me to set up, much less them.  (Plus, I'm not sure if windows has anything to support command-line based FTP processes -- and I'm stuck with windows because I can't afford a second box; a decent virtual machine is my long-term solution, but I don't have time to learn to work with it right now)

Comment: @RonLugge - you **must** write before, that you are GUI-biased. It costs me some additional time to prepare pure CLI-solution

Comment: @LazyBadger sorry about that.